# How can I pass a hidden form input in Laravel Livewire?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-livewire

Recently I had been trying to implement laravel's livewire to submit form and refresh the page without actually using the contemporary ajax based flow. It works fine for everything except that I need to send some hidden input values also which I would be changing based on the user's action before submitting the form.

```
<input type="text" class="w-100 ratings-hidden" value="" wire:model="rating_val">
<input class="" value=""  wire:model="reviewable_id"  type="hidden">
<textarea class="form-control w-100 animated" cols="50" id="new-review" wire:model="comment"  placeholder="Enter your review here..." rows="5"></textarea>
```

Here, the comment is fetched nicely after submission but I can not get the values of rating_val and reviewable_id

Comment: You probably don't need to have an hidden input, you can probably just have a property on the component, and maintain it through the users actions instead. Then instead of setting the value of that hidden input, just do `$set('reviewable_id', 'someValue')` (naturally depends on *how* you set it, which you haven't shown here).

Comment: Thanks, That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Remove the value="" from the input because livewire does it for you.

In your component set the properties, you need ($rating_val, $reviewable_id) and in your mount method, you initialise the value for those properties.

```
class ComponentName extends Component
{
   public $rating_val;
   public $reviewable_id;



  public function mount() 
  {
     $this->rating_val = "value_for_input";
     $this->reviewable_id = "value_for_input";
  }
}
```

In your blade file all you need is the following

```
<input type="hidden" wire:model="rating_val">
<input type="hidden" wire:model="reviewable_id">
```

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties

Answer (score -1):

you can't use hidden value or hidden input, but you can use this solution:

in your blade:

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="YourMethodName( {{ $param1 }} , {{ $param2 }})")>
    <button type="submit" >Sned</button>
</form>
```

in your component:

```
public function YourMethodName($param1 , $param2)
    {
        dd([
            'param1'=> $param1 ,
            'param2' => $param2,
        ]);
    }
```

It should be work, in the project I use this solution.